# ajax form sent n times for every nth select onchange event triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've have a small 'html' form with just a 'select' inside. When onchange event is triggered,
I want this form to be send as an AJAX request and show a jscript alert if an error occurred. 
The server is now sending an error code for every request. 
I set it up like that to test the popup alert.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="infoCommande" id="3">
    <div class="libelleEtatColis">
        <form method="post">

            <input type='hidden' name='idCommande' value="3"></input>

            <select name='etatCommande'>
                <option  value="-1"></option>
                <option selected value="1">EN PREPARATION</option>
                <option  value="2">ENVOYE</option>
                <option  value="3">ARCHIVE</option>
            </select>

            <div class="loadingFeedback"></div>
            <br />
            <br />
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here's my javascript. 
This first js block sets 'addEtatColisForm' as the function that will be called when the onchange event is triggered:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('.infoCommande').each(function(){
        var idCmd = this.id;

        $(this).find('.libelleEtatColis').find('select').change(
            function(){
                addEtatColisForm(this, idCmd);
            });
        });

    });
```

Aand here's the function that handles the form's submit using an AJAX request:

```
    function addEtatColisForm(htmlObj, idCmd){
        var frm = $(htmlObj).closest('form');

        console.log("1");

        frm.submit(function (ev){
            console.log("2");

            $.ajax({
                type: frm.attr('method'),
                url: frm.attr('action'),
                data: frm.serialize(),
                success: function(donnees){
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(donnees);
                    if( !(obj.error)){
                        frm.find('select').val(obj.result);
                    }else{
                        alert('Une erreur est arrivée lors de la modification de l\'état du colis.');
                    }
                }
            });

            ev.preventDefault();
        });

        //Submit form
        console.log("3");
        $(frm).trigger('submit');
    }
```

But... It isn't working as I expected... 
The first onchange is handled as expected. A popup alert is shown and that's all. 
The second onchange will fire 2 alert windows. 2 will be fired for the third onchange... 
And so on.

Lines:

```
console.log("1");
console.log("3");
```

Are only executing once for every onchange.

```
'console.log("2");'
```

however, it's executed 'n' times. I can't see why and it's been a little difficult to me to find something that will solve the problem, Maybe you'll have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding submit function to the form everytime you call addEtatColisForm function.
Try unbinding it first before binding it. ex:

```
frm.unbind('submit').bind("submit", function (ev){
```

Your can find the working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/z3UtC/1/

Or define the submit outside the function call (Following Simon's comments)
ex: http://jsfiddle.net/z3UtC/2/

Comment: More sensibly: bind the submit event handler outside the function and call `frm.submit()` inside the function.

Comment: Makes sense. Edited the ans accordingly. Thanks Simon.

Comment: Ok, thank you both! It works now! I thought 'bind' overwrote the previously binded function. I've already accepted EvilDevil answer and upvoted both the answer and Simon comment. Thanks again!